# Best Type of Chatbox in PHP

Tags: php, chat

I want to create a chatbox like gmail or facebook. What would be the best architecture to build it. Should It be good to use sockets or ajax?

If so, then would you please describe or give references of the architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest XMPP. I used it to design a chat system for within my companies software, and it worked quite well. There are plenty of XMPP libraries out there. If  you were so inclined though, it it possible to use some of Google's services. Not everything needs to be written from scratch:

https://developers.google.com/talk/open_communications